# Print DatagridView to rdlc Report

Tags: c#, printing, report, rdlc

How to print items from dataGridview , to rdlc Report.
The items in the dataGridView are filled manually, and not from database, that's why this gives me issues.

p.s i know there are ways to print it with PrintForm but i want to print it with .rdlc.

> Tryed with DataTable but it doenst show me the right colums on the
>   RDLC Dataset

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("ProdFromDGV");


            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dt.WriteXml("table.xml");`
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with DataTable, i tryed to fill a dataTable, than pass theese items into a DataSet but it doesnt show me the right columns.

Comment: I just edited the thread, you can see the code im using.

-- It doesnt show me the right Columns and Rows of the DataGrid it shows me nonsesence rows. i can post a screenshot if you want